# Cómo filtro la fecha más actual dentro de dos de mis base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Dentro de dos base de datos con igual columna requiero que solo se visualice dentro del campo "LOG_ID" de tipo TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE la fecha más actual guardada en la base de datos.

```sql
select "LOG_ID","LOG_DATE","REQ_START_DATE","ACTUAL_START_DATE","RUN_DURATION"
from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 

UNION ALL

select "LOG_ID","LOG_DATE","REQ_START_DATE","ACTUAL_START_DATE","RUN_DURATION"
from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS@DWH_ADS_ASEGSUR
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! la fecha mas actual se saca ordenando por fecha y quedandote con el primer registro.. que es muy diferente en mysql que en sql server. Porbaste algo de eso?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola israel, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, y en caso de que haya resuelto tu problema marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from
(
   select "LOG_ID","LOG_DATE","REQ_START_DATE","ACTUAL_START_DATE","RUN_DURATION"
   from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
   UNION
   select "LOG_ID","LOG_DATE","REQ_START_DATE","ACTUAL_START_DATE","RUN_DURATION"
   from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS@DWH_ADS_ASEGSUR 
)
order by "log_id" desc 
limit 1
```

Sobre la consulta original que ya tienes hecha se haría otra consulta que ordene los registros descendentemente por el campo log_id, de modo que el más reciente sea el primero y finalmente se emplearía la cláusula limit para escoger solamente el primer registro, el cual sería el más reciente.